# Найти точное вхождение email-а в поле таблицы MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, регулярные-выражения, like

В таблице `blacklist` MySQL есть поле `email` типа VARCHAR (255).
В нём могут записаны email-адреса, один или несколько через запятую.
Задача: проверять конкретный email-адрес на его наличие в таблице `blacklist`.

Допустим нам надо проверить email: test@mail.ru на его присутствие в таблице:
Вариант: **SELECT id FROM `blacklist` WHERE `email` LIKE '%test@mail.ru%'** - не подойдет, потому как в поле таблице может быть записан адрес, например 123test@mail.ru - который для данного запроса ложно сработает!

Так как в поле `email` может быть один или несколько email-адресов разделенных запятыми, можно сформулировать словесно следующий вариант поиска:

Найти точное вхождение строки в поле, учитывая такие варианты её расположения в поле, на примере test@mail.ru:

- начало поля **test@mail.ru** конец поля (один email в поле)
- начало поля **test@mail.ru** запятая или конец поля (email находится вначале поля)
- запятая **test@mail.ru** запятая или конец поля (email находится в середине или конце поля)

**Как записать такое регулярное выражение в MySQL?**

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант использовать несколько LIKE

```
WHERE email LIKE '%,test@mail.ru,%'
OR email LIKE 'test@mail.ru,%'
OR email LIKE '%,test@mail.ru'
```

Comment: А может существует конструкция типа `email LIKE IN(....)`? Как-то в регулярки на SQL я не верю..

Comment: Спасибо! Запрос вида: SELECT * FROM `blacklist` WHERE email LIKE 'test@mail.ru' OR email LIKE 'test@mail.ru,%' OR email LIKE '%,test@mail.ru' OR email LIKE '%,test@mail.ru,%' отлично сработал!

Comment: Сработать то сработал, но почему-то щемит в душе после взгляда на этот код =) Наверное плохо так делать и работать будет медленно..

Comment: Использую для формирования рассылки писем, от 10 000 писем, т.е. получаю 10 000 тыс. таких запросов, распределенных по времени в цикле, пока что всё работает хорошо без нареканий. Код не идеальный, лучше бы применить регулярку наверное, но в голову хорошего изящного решения пока не приходит )

Comment: @Enshtein, с указанной вами схемой, врядли можно сделать быстро выполняющийся запрос . Я предлагаю вам хранить почтовые адреса в отдельной таблице и связать ее с таблицей blacklist отношением один-ко-многим. Это позволит вам делать выборки более оптимальным и быстрым способом. Demo - https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jCMrR7gBvirBKUkFmew53i/1